# Custom notification maximum height?

Tags: android, android-layout

I am trying to make a custom notification and it always ends up being pretty small (about the size of most notifications). I can see that Netflix and Youtube display much larger notifications which look custom (they might be big view) when casting to a chromecast device. How are they making them that large?

Thanks.

EDIT: Marked it as answered because of the comment pointing out [bigContentView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Notification.html#bigContentView)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You seem to already know... You're probably talking about big view style notifications. Google has [specific training documentation](http://developer.android.com/training/notify-user/expanded.html) as well as [a technical guide](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/notifications.html#ApplyStyle) for that. Here's some example code from there:

```
// Constructs the Builder object.
NotificationCompat.Builder builder =
        new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
        .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_stat_notification)
        .setContentTitle(getString(R.string.notification))
        .setContentText(getString(R.string.ping))
        .setDefaults(Notification.DEFAULT_ALL) // requires VIBRATE permission
        /*
         * Sets the big view "big text" style and supplies the
         * text (the user's reminder message) that will be displayed
         * in the detail area of the expanded notification.
         * These calls are ignored by the support library for
         * pre-4.1 devices.
         */
        .setStyle(new NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle()
                .bigText(msg))
        .addAction (R.drawable.ic_stat_dismiss,
                getString(R.string.dismiss), piDismiss)
        .addAction (R.drawable.ic_stat_snooze,
                getString(R.string.snooze), piSnooze);
```

Note the call to `setStyle`.

Comment: Yeah I've already used Big View style notifications, but I guess I was hoping there was a way I could make a custom notification the size of a Big View notification.

Comment: Ah, I see. You can use [`bigContentView`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Notification.html#bigContentView).

Comment: thx @kabuko, You saved my day by considering `bigContentView` and its link.